# PHP shell_exec failed due to some specific character

Tags: php, shell-exec, mailx

I'm using `shell_exec` function to call `mailx` command on Ubuntu to send mail, but received error as there is specific character in the command, please see my below code and result.

```
<?php
$stringA="Visit STAR WARS™";
$stringB="Visit STAR WARS";

echo "StringA:", $stringA, "<br/>";
$res = shell_exec("echo $stringA | mailx -s 'testA' my_email_address@mail.com");
echo $res, "<br/>";

echo "StringB:", $stringB, "<br/>";
$res = shell_exec("echo $stringB | mailx -s 'testB' my_email_address@mail.com");
echo $res, "<br/>";
```

When I call this page on the server, I got below page:

```
StringA: Visit STAR WARS™
"/var/www/dead.letter" 1/19 
StringB: Visit STAR WARS
```

and I received the mail with content `Visit STAR WARS`, and cannot received the mail with content `Visit STAR WARS™`.

I checked from the phpinfo function, and the default_charset is "utf-8".
if i run the command `"echo Visit STAR WARS™ | mailx -s 'testB' my_email_address@mail.com"`directly on the Ubuntu shell, I can get the mail with **™**content.

Can anyone help me to fix the problem so that shell_exec function can send mail with specific characters.

Comment: `shell_exec("echo -n \"$stringA\"| mailx -s 'testA' my_email_address@mail.com");`

Comment: use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape your special chars

Comment: @Cyclonecode I tested it, but the problem persist.

Comment: @hassan, `$stringA=escapeshellarg("Visit STAR WARS™"); $res = shell_exec("echo -n $stringA | mailx -s 'test' tiancheng.li@sony.com");` cannot help me, the problem still persist.

Comment: What is return value of shell_exec? Chceck stderr (by redirecting stderr to stdout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` [dollar sign] has a special meaning in shell scripts , so you can not pass it within the command ,

```
$res = shell_exec("echo '" . $stringA . "' | mailx -s 'testA' my_email_address@mail.com");
```

and it's always better to use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape your arguments as follows :

```
$res = shell_exec("echo '" . escapeshellarg($stringA) . "' | mailx -s 'testA' my_email_address@mail.com");
```

Comment: it's a bit strange. if I add the escapeshellarg in the variable definition, the error gone. `$stringA=escapeshellarg ("Visit STAR WARS™"); `, if not (`$stringA="Visit STAR WARS™"; `), the problem still persists. However, I couldn't received the mail thought the error gone.

Comment: then your need to trace your mailx execution

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this by setting the character set on `mailx`. `mailx -S ttycharset=utf-8 -S sendcharsets=utf-8 ...`